# Horizontal slide banner design & functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to show the vertical banner which will slide out horizontally from the right of the screen once user click the open button/div and should be able to close the same. Base design is show in the sample image below

[image]

I have set up fiddle for the same http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXgePX

```
<div class="horizontal-slide" id="other-menu"><<</div>


<div class="menu-other slide-right slide-opened" id="other-menu-content">
  horizontal on right slide div
</div>
```

**UPDATE**:

I managed to do it by wrapping banner & button inside another div.

```
.wrapper{
  float:right;
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
}
```

example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOzyxo

still need to improve it so that button also slides with the banner for smooth look

Comment: Looks like its working perfectly

Comment: I need to fix the design so that button also move as show in image and text of button also change from `<` to `>`...

Comment: I have updated fiddle to change the text inside button, need to fix the design so that button show on left of the banner.

Comment: What you need to look at here is putting the button inside the blue container and setting it to absolute position and the container to relative position. Hopefully that will help a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You've to change your css

For example:

```
/* float */
float:right;

/* absolute position */
position:absolute;
```

You need it like this:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJyMgW

Or do I missunderstand your Question?

Comment: Your code has positioned button to left  of banner but it is not moving red button to right when banner is closing, It should also move red button to eight of the screen as shown in the image posted in my question.

Comment: I also manage to do it http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOzyxo. but it still need to be fine tuned..

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you wanted something like this. It's a good start I think.

```js
$(function() {

  //slideout-menu-toggle
  $(".banner-slide").click(function(event) {
    var _slideMenu = $("#right-banner");
    if (_slideMenu.hasClass("slide-opened")) {
      $( "#right-banner" ).animate({ "right": "-190px" }, "slow" );
      $(  "#hbanner" ).html("<<");
      //alert('a')
    } else {
      $( "#right-banner" ).animate({ "right": "0" }, "slow" );
      $(  "#hbanner" ).html(">>");
    }

    _slideMenu.toggleClass("slide-opened");
  });
});
```

```css
#right-banner {
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  top: 0;
  width: 210px;
}

.right-banner {
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  padding: 20px;
  float: right;
  background-color: blue;
}

#hbanner {
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.wrapper {
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 100000;
}

.content {
  width: calc(100% - 210px);
  background-color: magenta;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  This is sample text</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="right-banner" class="slide-opened">
    <div class="banner-slide" id="hbanner">
      >>
    </div>

    <div class="right-banner" id="hbanner-wrapper">
     horizontal on right slide div
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it cleaner and simpler using CSS transitions and a simple toggleClass in jQuery:

```
$('#button').on('click', function(){
    $('#banner').toggleClass('unfolded');
});
```

Demo : http://codepen.io/mbrillaud/pen/NqPvZM

Answer (score 0):

use a JQ toggle class

```
$('#slider').toggleClass('sliderthing');
```

that plus CSS to give it looks and stuff should work well

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it by wrapping the banner & button inside another wrapper.

Here is the updated example : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOzyxo

I have added some exact animation so that red button hide/shows immediately upon click event with some smooth animation.

```
.wrapper{
  float:right;
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  z-index:100000;
}
```